# Is $F=\Bbb {Q} (\sqrt 2, \sqrt [3]2, \sqrt [4] 2,...)$ different from $\bar {\Bbb {Q}} $?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Is $F=\Bbb {Q} (\sqrt 2, \sqrt [3]2, \sqrt [4] 2,...)$ different from algebraic closure $\bar {\Bbb {Q}} $ of $\Bbb {Q} $ in $\Bbb {C} $?
**Try**

I tried to proof by contradiction.
Since $\sqrt 3$ is a root of $x^2-3$, hence $\sqrt 3 \in \bar {\Bbb {Q}} $. Our claim is $\sqrt 3 \notin F$

Assume on the contrary that $\sqrt 3 \in F$. Then $\sqrt 3 \in K=\Bbb {Q} (\sqrt 2, \sqrt [3]2,...,\sqrt [n] 2)\subset F$ for some integer $n$. Now $\sqrt 3=a+b\sqrt [n] 2$ for some $a, b \in \Bbb {Q} (\sqrt 2, \sqrt [3]2,...,\sqrt [n-1] 2)$.
Now $3=a^2+b^2 \sqrt [n]4+2ab\sqrt [n] 2$.
I'm stucked here. Am I on the right track? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It breaks down after your first 'Now'.

Comment: Just note that $i\not\in F$ and you are done.

Comment: @Trebor - You might want to tell the OP why it breaks down after the first "Now."

Comment: @Dietrich Burde then also I have to prove that $i\notin F$. Isn't it?

Comment: But it is obvious that $i\not \in F$.  Your field is totally real.  It's a more interesting question if you adjoin all the conjugates as you add roots.

Comment: As written the answer is obvious. Qf course one can modify the question to make it more interesting, but perhaps this is not necessary. It just is clear that such $F$ are different from $\overline{\Bbb Q}$.

Comment: As @Dietrich Burde suggest, I request any moderator to edit the question to make it more interesting. Will anybody like to do that?